# Learning Recursion Java

Tags: java

What does the following method compute?  Assume the method is called initially with i = 0

```
public int mysteryMethod(String a, char b, int i) {
    if (i == a.length())
        return 0;
    else if (b == a.charAt(i))
        return mysteryMethod(a, b, i + 1) + 1;
    else
        return mysteryMethod(a, b, i + 1);
}
```

I'm confused about recursion. On the second return statement what's the +1 doing.

Comment: I assume you don't want us to give you the actual answer but just a hint?

Comment: yeah any help or explanation on recursion would be nice :)

Comment: Try to avoid the temptation to "unroll" a recursive function into steps, thus turning it into an imperative programming style in your head. Instead, try to think of the function as a *definition* rather than a recipe. Think in terms of *what* instead of *how*.

Comment: I suggest you just try it on lots and lots of strings. You'll soon spot what it does. They you can start trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second if statement, the +1 is counting something. So here is a hint.

> What is the +1 counting?

**Stop reading here and keep trying. Then continue reading for the next hint.**

To answer this question above, you should look at the condition in which the +1 will happen. This is when `b` is equal to `a.charAt(i)`.

> So what does this mean with respect to counting?

**Stop reading here and keep trying. Continue reading for the answer.**

The function is counting the number of times `b` occurs in the string `a`. On each iteration, it checks if the iteration (ith) position is equal to `b`. If so, increase the count by one and repeat the function from the next position. Otherwise, just continue and check the next iteration.